# Есть ли способы скрыть src у iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Есть ли какие-то возможные методы с помощью которых можно скрыть src у iframe, чтоб через dev tools видно небыло в инспекторе?

Comment: сделать отрисовку документа с помощью канваса)

Comment: @Sergey Novikov причём тут canvas. Необходимо чтобы src не был виден в инспекторе  при просмотре страницы.

Comment: Это фантастика!

Comment: Конечно, можно :). Запрашивайте содержимое `iframe`-а по "секретному" адресу на сервере.

Comment: Если не в инспекторе, так каким-нибудь другим способом найдут

Comment: @EVG canvas не причем, но и в инспекторе, все что в канвасе не будет отображаться, `<canvas></canvas>` , а в канвас можно запихнуть разметку)

Comment: _Необходимо чтобы src не был виден в инспекторе при просмотре страницы_ - инспектор не является частью страницы, поэтому если у элемента есть атрибут, он его покажет.